# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown'

Tags: php, exception, activex

Does anybody know anything about this error in COM function in PHP?:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception'
with message '<b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown'
in C:\my\php\file\path.php
Stack trace:
#0 C:\my\php\file\path.php: com->init('pincode', NULL)
#1 {main}
thrown in C:\my\php\file\path.php on line 7
```

I am trying to call a Activex in my PHP code in order to use its methods. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?PHP
$active = new COM("sswATL.crypto");
//------------------------

$pass = "pincode";

$ret = $active->init( $pass , $retVal);

if($retVal == 0){ 
   print "Login successfully";
}
elseif($retVal == 4){

   print "Token is not present";
} 
else
{
   $errMsg = "Login failed : "; 
   print $errMsg;
  }
?>
```

I believe that `sswATL.crypto` is well loaded in my PHP, because when I call `init` with wrong parameters, for example `init('pincode')`, I've got the error in number of arguments in this method. any ideas?

Comment: you installed COM extension in php??

Comment: It's already installed, cause when I run the php.net sample about COM function which it open a word document with COM("word.application"), it works fine.